# TypeError: X is not a function. Node.js - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

This code is a working solution for Web Api Controller. The problems start when I am trying to implement separation of concerns and import `fetchWebApi(url)` from `const { fetchWebApi } = require('./fetchWebApiController')`. It gives me the following error: `curValue` is not a function. Not sure why it says function. `curValue` is not a function . It is just a variable that is used as a variable and never called as a function. Here is the [link](https://github.com/forza11879/nodeApp/blob/master/controllers/webApiController.js) to github project.

**webApiController.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')
// const { fetchWebApi } = require('./fetchWebApiController')
const { Stock } = require('../models/Stock')

exports.getWebApi = (req, res) => {
  let curValue = req.params.symbol
  console.log(`${curValue} - seacrhBox value`)
  console.log(typeof curValue)

  const urlCompact = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${curValue}&outputsize=compact&apikey=6BUYSS9QR8Y9HH15`

  async function fetchWebApi(url) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      return parsedData = await Object.keys(response.data['Time Series (Daily)']).map(date => {
        return {
          date: Date.parse(date),
          open: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']) * 100) / 100,
          high: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['2. high']) * 100) / 100,
          low: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['3. low']) * 100) / 100,
          close: Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['4. close']) * 100) / 100,
          volume: parseInt(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['5. volume'])
        }
      })
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(`fetchWebApi error: ${ex}`)
    }
  }

  (async function creatStock() {//line33
    try {
      const webApiData = await fetchWebApi(urlCompact)
      const stock = new Stock({
        symbol: curValue,
        data: webApiData
      })

      const query = { symbol: `${curValue}` }
      const update = { $addToSet: { data: stock.data } }
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }

      const stockResult = await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
      console.log('Saved the symbol web TO db', stockResult.symbol)
      return res.send(webApiData)

    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(`creatStock error: ${ex}`)
    }
  })()
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: curValue is not a function
    at exports.getWebApi (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/controllers/webApiController.js:33:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: It means that `req.params.symbol` is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure the code shown here is completely correct? To produce that error, you'd have to have `curValue()`. What do your two `console.log` calls at the top of `getWebApi` show?

Comment: @Phil The code is working perfectly. The only time it is getting me an error is when I am trying to import `fetchWebApi(urlCompact)`. `console.log` at the top shows the input value of the type string.

Comment: Really don't know what you mean. Where is that code? Also, which line is 33 in `webApiController.js`? That's where the stack-trace shows the error originating

Comment: @Phil this is the function where it is being called `creatStock()`

Comment: Again, this doesn't make any sense. Which piece of code in your question is from `webApiController.js`? Which is line 33? You mention `const { fetchWebApi } = require('./fetchWebApiController')` but what does that have to do with your question? That code isn't present in any executable form

Comment: There is no code on the `//line 33` so that cannot possibly throw an error

Comment: @Phil updated the code to reflect line 33.

Comment: @Phil line 33 `(async function creatStock() {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188776/discussion-between-john-john-and-phil).

Comment: I don't think the code in this question matches your actual code

Comment: @Phil I will send you my github link. one sec

Comment: @Phil here is the link to github https://github.com/forza11879/nodeApp/blob/master/controllers/webApiController.js

Comment: Assuming you're making changes while your app is running, have you tried restarting the app?

Comment: @Phil Yes, I tried it all . Not sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: @Phil It is not crucial just wanted to implement separation of concerns of the function

Comment: Just ran your code. `console.log(typeof curValue)` is saying `string`, which is not a function. So, wherever you're calling it like `curValue()`, it's failing there.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb `curValue` is not a function . it is just a reglar variable. I never call it as a function. I use it as a regular variable